# Subsequence proof of the continuous mapping principle for convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> **Theorem.** Let $f$ be a continuous function. If $X_n \to_p X$, then $f(X_n) \to_p f(X)$.

($\to_p$ denotes convergence in probability.)

The proof I am looking at goes

> Let $\{f(X_{n_k})\}$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $\{f(X_n)\}$. Since $X_n \to_p X$, we have $X_{n_k} \to_p X$, which implies that there exists a subsequence $\{X_{n_{k_i}}\}$ of $\{X_{n_k}\}$ such that $X_{n_{k_i}} \to_{a.s.} X$, which in turn implies that $f(X_{n_{k_i}}) \to_{a.s.} f(X)$, by the continuous mapping principle for a.s. convergence. From that we deduce that $f(X_{n_{k_i}}) \to_{p} f(X)$.
>   We have thus shown that any subsequence $\{f(X_{n_k})\}$ of $f(X_n)$ has a subsequence $\{f(X_{n_{k_i}})\}$ such that $f(X_{n_{k_i}}) \to_p f(X)$. This establishes that $f(X_n)\to_p f(X)$.

It is only this last step I do not understand. **How does that any subsequence of the original sequence has a convergent subsequence imply the original sequence being convergent?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If not, then for some positive $\varepsilon_0$, we do not have the convergence of $\left(\mathbb P\left(\left|f(X_n)-f(X)\right|\gt\varepsilon_0\right)\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ to $0$. This means that there exists an increasing sequence of positive integers $(n_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ such that $\inf_{k\geqslant 1}\mathbb P\left(\left|f\left(X_{n_k}\right)-f(X)\right|\gt\varepsilon_0\right)\gt 0$. This contradicts what was proved because a further subsequence of $\left(f\left(X_{n_k}\right)\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ cannot converge in probability to $f(X)$.